# Logo and menus are not aligned

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem is that I want the logo and ΛΟΓΙΣΜΙΚΟ menu to be aligned.
I've tried everything and I can't make them move together. The menus move a lot faster...
I'm trying with javascript to get the positions and set the logo to move with the same position as the menu but I can't figure it out here is the page http://www.altasoft.gr/index_.htm

```
<div class="header">
    <div style="position:relative;top:10px; z-index:99; width:50%"><a href="http://www.altasoft.gr/index_.htm"><img  src="images/Altasoft_Logo.png" alt="" width="354" height="91" /></a></div>
    <div style="position:relative; left:10%; top:-30px; z-index:5; width:80%; min-width:550px;"> <img style="float:right;" src="images/telephone.gif" alt="" width="142" height="16" /></div>
</div>
```

```
.nav-container {
    background: #eaeaeb;
    /*background: #fff url(../images/menu_bg.gif) no-repeat 50% 0%;*/
    clear: both;
    height: 48px;
}
#nav {
    /*padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;*/
    width: 931px/*920px*/;
}
#nav li {
    padding-right: 8px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey actually you should follow the mentioned below code i hope this will work for you please change your `header` **DIV** code with my code :-

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
    <div style="margin: auto; width: 931px;"><a href="http://www.altasoft.gr/index_.htm"><img width="354" height="91" alt="" src="images/Altasoft_Logo.png"></a></div>
     
      
     <div style="position:relative; left:10%; top:-30px; z-index:5; width:80%; min-width:550px;"> <img width="142" height="16" alt="" src="images/telephone.gif" style="float:right;"></div>
       </div>
```

U have to remove the **position** property from your `logo div` and its `position values` **top** & **left** and just define the `width:931px;` with `margin:auto` and its working fine as per your requirement....

**[image: see the attached demo]**

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="header">
    <div style="left: 17%;
top: 10px;
z-index: 99;
width: 859px;
margin: auto;"><a href="http://www.altasoft.gr/index_.htm"><img width="354" height="91" alt="" src="images/Altasoft_Logo.png"></a></div>


     <div style="position:relative; left:10%; top:-30px; z-index:5; width:80%; min-width:550px;"> <img width="142" height="16" alt="" src="images/telephone.gif" style="float:right;"></div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the width of the #nav

Screenshot:

[image]